# Finding smallest possible values of theta

Tags: trigonometry

I'm really stuck on this problem and would appreciate some help.

Find the smallest possible values of $\theta$ for which the gradient is $0$

$$y = \sin2 \theta - 3\cos2 \theta$$

Thanks.

Comment: For formulas, look at http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex
What have you done so far?

Comment: differentiate this and put it equal to 0, then solve for theta. To write theta on here, put \theta with $ before and after expression.

Comment: @Jacoabadtr : $y$ appears to be a function of only one variable, so "derivative" is a better word than "gradient".  Also, using \sin and \cos (with \$ before and after) gives you $\sin$ and $\cos$ and is easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

$y'(\theta)=2\cos(2\theta)+6\sin(2\theta)=0\iff\tan(2\theta)=-1/3
\iff2\theta=\arctan(-1/3)+k\pi$ for $k\in\boldsymbol Z$, hence
$$\theta=\frac12\bigl((\arctan(-1/3)+k\pi\bigr)\quad\text{for $k\in\boldsymbol Z$}.$$
Thus no smallest $\theta$ exists. But there is obviously a smallest *positive* $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The differential will give you the gradient, differentiate this and put it equal to zero, then solve for $\theta$